# Delayed insert due to foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql, insert, foreign-keys, delay

I am trying to run a query:

```
INSERT
  INTO `ProductState` (`ProductId`, `ChangedOn`, `State`)
SELECT t.`ProductId`, t.`ProcessedOn`, \'Activated\'
  FROM `tmpImport` t
  LEFT JOIN `Product` p
    ON t.`ProductId` = p.`Id`
 WHERE p.`Id` IS NULL
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       `ChangedOn` = VALUES(`ChangedOn`)
```

(I am not quite sure the query is correct, but it appears to be working), however I am running into the following issue.  I am running this query before creating the entry into the 'Products' table and am getting a foreign key constraint problem due to the fact that the entry is not in the Products table yet.

My question is, is there a way to run this query, but wait until the next query (which updates the Product table) before performing the insert portion of the query above?  Also to note, if the query is run after the Product entry is created it will no longer see the p.`Id` as being null and therefore failing so it has to be performed before the Product entry is created.

---> Edit <---
The concept I am trying to achieve is as follows:
For starters I am importing a set of data into a temp table, the `Product` table is a list of all products that are (or have been in the past) added through the set of data from the temp table.  What I need is a separate table that provides a state change to the product as sometimes the product will become unavailable (no longer in the data set provided by the vendor).

The ProductState table is as follows:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ProductState` (
  `ProductId` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
  `ChangedOn` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `State` ENUM('Activated','Deactivated') NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ProductId`, `ChangedOn`) ,
  INDEX `fk_ProductState_Product` (`ProductId` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ProductState_Product`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ProductId` )
    REFERENCES `Product` (`Id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

The foreign key is an identifying relationship with the Product table (`Product`.`Id`)

Essentially what I am trying to accomplish is this:
1. Anytime a new product (or previously deactivated product) shows up in the vendor data set, the record is created in the ProductState table as 'Activated'.
2. Anytime a product (that is activated), does not show up in the vendor data set, the record is created as 'Deactivated' in the ProductState table.

The purpose of the ProductState table is to track activation and deactivation states of a product. Also the ProductState is a Multi-To-One relationship with the Product Table, and the state of the product will only change once daily, therefore my PKEY would be ProductId and ChangedDate.

Comment: On a side note, is there a way to perform multiple inserts on select queries (that might be the solution, inserting to multiple tables with the one select query)

Comment: any reason why you need to insert to the ProductState before you insert the product?

Comment: @tsOverflow my logic (which may be at fault here), is that once the Product entry exists, the above query will no longer find it as being null (because it exists), but again with logic issues, if it already exists (but is deactivated) it also would fail in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With foreign keys, you definitely need to have the data on the Product table first, before entering the state, think about it with this logic: "How can something that dont exist have a state" ?

So pseudocode of what you should do:

1. Read in the vendor's product list
2. Compare them to the existing list in your Product table
3. If new ones found: 3.1 Insert it to Product table, 3.2 Insert it to ProductState table
4. If missing from vendor's list: 4.1 Insert it to ProductState table

All these should be done in 1 transaction. Note that you should NOT delete things from Product table, unless you really want to delete every information associated with it, ie. also delete all the "states" that you have stored.

Rather than trying to do this all in 1 query - best bet is to create a stored procedure that does the work as step-by-step above. I think it gets overly complicated (or in this case, probably impossible) to do all in 1 query.

Edit: Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `some_procedure_name` ()
BEGIN

-- Breakdown the tmpImport table to 2 tables: new and removed
SELECT * INTO _temp_new_products
FROM`tmpImport` t
LEFT JOIN `Product` p
ON t.`ProductId` = p.`Id`
WHERE p.`Id` IS NULL

SELECT * INTO _temp_removed_products
FROM `Product` p
LEFT JOIN `tmpImport` t 
ON t.`ProductId` = p.`Id`
WHERE t.`ProductId` IS NULL

-- For each entry in _temp_new_products:
-- 1. Insert into Product table
-- 2. Insert into ProductState table 'activated'

-- For each entry in _temp_removed_products:
-- 1. Insert into ProductState table 'deactivated'

-- drop the temporary tables
DROP TABLE _temp_new_products
DROP TABLE _temp_removed_products
END
```

Comment: I think that was exactly what I was looking for.  I haven't used procedures before, but your example gives me a clear understanding of what 'logic' I need to follow, and I was actually thinking of doing this through a couple of temp tables (new/removed) as part of a fix, through procedures this may simplify everything.  Will get back to you shortly to accept your solution once I put this into effect.

Comment: Solution accepted - that worked perfectly, **and** I am now going to move some other logic (auditing information) into other procedures, that works slick!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should:

- start a transaction
- do your insert into the `Products` table
- do your insert into the `ProductState` table
- commit the transaction

This will avoid any foreign key errors, but will also make sure your data is always accurate. You do not want to 'avoid' the foreign key constraint in any way, and InnoDB (which I'm sure you are using) never defers these constraints unless you turn them off completely.

Also no you cannot insert into multiple tables in one INSERT ... SELECT statement.

Comment: I get the start/commit transaction part, however, I need to run the select portion of the query at very least prior to updating the Product table, and then the insert portion after (but still requires the results from the select) I am not clear on how to perform that logic with mysql queries (and definitely want to avoid processing via php on a line by line basis as that is extremely slow and the whole point of dealing with temp tables and insert/select queries)

Comment: @Aaron Murray - frankly you are doing something wrong, or I completely misunderstand you. Your Product table insertion/update must be possible before creating the ProductState record or your database model has big problems. Can you explain in words and tables (by editing your question) precisely what the before and after of your tables should look like? This will help us determine the best solution.

Comment: I need to run the select portion of the query at very least prior to updating the Product table >> How would this be possible? I am with Henry here, there is something weird in your logic.

Comment: You could very well be right my logic may be out of whack - I have updated my description

Comment: @tsOverflow I have updated my description, it is quite possible there is a flaw in my logic.