# Slow mysql query / Possible query problem

Tags: mysql, performance

I have 2 (similar) queries:

```
-- Query #1 - get all new products not in currently in the Product table
-- Should match any products in the temp table that do not exist in the Product table
INSERT
  INTO `tmpProductState` (`ProductId`, `ChangedOn`, `State`)
SELECT t.`ProductId`, t.`ProcessedOn`, \'Activated\'
  FROM `tmpImport` t
  LEFT JOIN `Product` p USING (`ProductId`)
 WHERE p.`ProductId` IS NULL
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       `State` = VALUES(`State`)

-- Query #2 - get all Products that are removed from the Product table
-- Should match any products in the Product table that do not exist in the temp table
INSERT
  INTO `tmpProductState` (`ProductId`, `ChangedOn`, `State`)
SELECT p.`ProductId`, p.`LastSeenDate`, \'Deactivated\'
  FROM `Product` p
  LEFT JOIN `tmpImport` t USING (`ProductId`)
 WHERE t.`ProductId` IS NULL
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       `State` = VALUES(`State`)
```

On first run, (day 1), when the Product table is empty, both queries run in under 1 second, however, on second run, (day 2), when the Product table has 14000 records, the first query runs in under 2 seconds, and the second query runs in 244 seconds. Each consecutive data import is the same (240-250 seconds for query # 2.  On checking the database, all data seems correct, I just can't figure out why the second query is taking so long.

---> Edit: Slow Query log:

```
# Query_time: 245.328784  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 187711973
SET timestamp=1305151558;

INSERT
  INTO `tmpProductState` (`ProductId`, `ChangedOn`, `State`)
SELECT p.`ProductId`, p.`LastSeenDate`, 'Deactivated'
  FROM `Product` p
  LEFT JOIN `tmpImport` t USING (`ProductId`)
 WHERE t.`ProductId` IS NULL
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       `State` = VALUES(`State`);
```

What concerns me most at this point: Rows_examined: 187711973 (how exactly is it examining that many rows?)  The Product table size is ~14000 records, and the import table size is ~28000 records, and the tmpProductState is at most 60 records.

---> Another Edit:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT p.`ProductId` , p.`LastSeenDate` , 'Deactivated'
FROM `Product` p
LEFT JOIN `tmpImport` t
USING ( `ProductId` )
WHERE t.`ProductId` IS NULL 

id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          p       ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL            NULL    14151
1   SIMPLE          t       index   NULL            PRIMARY 100             NULL    28166   Using where; Using index; Not exists
```

Tables Involved:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tmpImport` (
  `CategoryId`             smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ProcessedOn`            date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProductId`              varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Title`                  varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description`            text,
  `ActivateDate`           date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CategoryId`,`ProductId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = UTF8

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tmpProductState` (
  `ProductId` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `ChangedOn` DATE NOT NULL,
  `State` ENUM(\'Activated\',\'Deactivated\'),
  PRIMARY KEY(`ProductId`,`ChangedOn`)
) ENGINE = Memory

CREATE TABLE `Product` (
  `ProductId` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` text,
  `ActivateDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastSeenDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ProductId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: I didn't understand why you are doing this (copying data to the other table) and why you are running queries this way.. maybe, knowing the structure of the tables could help in finding a better way to do what you need

Comment: Please could you include details of the table structure (`SHOW CREATE TABLES`) and also the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` on the `SELECT` portions of the queries.

Comment: @JamesC I could do that if I knew how to do the explain part on temporary (session specific) tables.

Comment: You can also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967572/delayed-insert-due-to-foreign-key-constraints for further information on what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: @James C I have updated info as requested

Answer (score 0):

Your tables are not normalized, you don't have effective indexes, and your joins are... unusual.

I assume you can't do anything about the gross duplication of data across tables, so lets ignore that.

Looks like you are duplicating data across columns in the tables you are joining, you should use all of those columns in your join. So it should probably be:

```
LEFT JOIN `tmpImport` t USING (`ProductId`, `Title`, `Description`, `ActivateDate`)
```

Add indexes to your tables that correspond to the fields you are joining or filtering on. DO NOT have a compound key as your primary key. Instead add an auto incrementing field to be the PK, and have a unique key if you need to enforce uniqueness. Both the product table and tmpImport should have keys for each column being joined.

Hope some of these ideas help you out.

Comment: @invertedSpear I don't agree with you, my tables are normalized, I have no duplication (with the exception of the temp tables where I am processing data from the vendor which is very un-normal) into sensible tables.  I do not believe that my problem has anything to do with compound indexes (nor do I see creating compound primary keys as wrong when it comes to columns that need to be unique). Most of my tables have a primary key that composes of the ProductId and a Date that corresponds to the data within the table (since most of my information is daily information)

Comment: As far as having having a key for each column being joined, I am joining by ProductId only as that is the only column that is unique and all other columns may differ. (As in the title could be different in the temp table than it is in the product table, which I have other queries that check for that and put it into an audit table)  So I either I am really missing your point, or you are far from understanding what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: And finally, you have not made any suggestions as to why my second query is running through 187711973 rows.

Comment: @Aaron: The temp table is where there is bad normalization, it's what's killing your queries and providing you with so many records due to cross joining. If the same product ID could have different data in the same named fields across multiple tables there is other problems going on here as well. Fixing the normalization of the tmpTable before doing your import will reduce the cross joining and reduce the record counts. I may be misunderstanding, but I'm doing the best I can with what you're providing. Not knowing what you can and can't cut makes helping your particular situation difficult.

Comment: @invertedSpear the whole purpose of the main temp table (tmpImport) is to get all the information into a table so that I can run queries across it to put the proper data into the appropriate live tables.

Comment: @invertedSpear   All of my other queries (run at a speed of 1 second or less populating other tables, the only query I am having trouble with is the query listed above which is finding all ProductId's in the Product table that don't exist in the tmpImport table ProductId's (which would therefore mean they are no longer listed in the vendors database as being active), once I get that list of products I can then set the product in my ProductState table to 'Deactivated' (now note I am not removing it from my product table as the product may be reactivated down the road,

Comment: @invertedSpear  at which point I will set the state to 'Activated'.  As with the first query I listed, I am joining the two tables to find the opposite information, I want to know what products are in the temp table and not in the product table (so I can set the state to active (and yes I realize I am missing anything that is already in the Product table and just previously 'Deactivated', but the query works as it is written in under 2 seconds, what I am not understanding is how reversing the join is running itself through a 187M rows.

Answer (score 0):

Very late reply to this, but your first query is getting all the records from *tmpImport* and they getting all the records from *Product* using the primary key on the Product table. This is pretty efficient. The second query is getting all the records from *Product* and then getting the matching records from *tmpImport* but without the benefit of any index on *ProductId* on *tmpImport*. Hence runs badly.

Add an index on *ProductId* to the *tmpImport* table (the *ProductId* in the primary key is ignored for this join as it is not the first column in the key and you are not using *CategoryId* which is the first ).